# How do I fix `npm install` errors with react-boilerplate?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-boilerplate

When I run `npm install` from a react-boilerplate project several of my 3rd party modules give off errors like you see below. All these modules work fine in other node projects, just not in react-boilerplate. Does anyone know how to fix these?

```
ERROR in ./~/nconf/lib/nconf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/me/src/fullboar/probate-web/node_modules/nconf/lib'
 @ ./~/nconf/lib/nconf.js 8:9-22

ERROR in ./~/nconf/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/me/src/fullboar/probate-web/node_modules/nconf/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       {
 @ ./~/nconf/lib/nconf.js 21:16-42

ERROR in ./~/nconf/lib/nconf/common.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/me/src/fullboar/probate-web/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf'
 @ ./~/nconf/lib/nconf/common.js 8:9-22

ERROR in ./~/sequelize/package.json
Module parse failed: /Users/me/src/fullboar/probate-web/node_modules/sequelize/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       {
 @ ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js 265:20-46
```

Comment: try updating your node to latest version

Comment: I'm running `v4.5.0`

Comment: I have the same problem and non of the solution did not worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I've the same issue on `fs` package.

```
ERROR in dll reactBoilerplateDeps
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/nico/_dev/crf'
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
```

To avoid this error I ignore the `fs` module for browser builds updating the [`webpack.dll.babel.js`](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.dll.babel.js) file like this:

```
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({ name: '[name]', path: join(outputPath, '[name].json') }), // eslint-disable-line no-new
  ],

  // mock fs
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
};
```

I don't know if is the best solution, but for me works fine.

**NOTE**

Before:

- I tried to `rm -r node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install` but the error remained
- I inserted the `fs` dependency in the dllPlugin `exclude` array in  [internals/config.js](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/config.js) file, but the error remained

**Documentation**

[`node`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#node) key in webpack config include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff